# Not sending message, subject, or from who it is?

Tags: php, forms, email, post, contacts

I made a contact form but it's not sending the message, subject, and the e-mail of the person that contacts me?

Contact.php : prntscr.com/5uj9mo

Index.php : prntscr.com/5uj9zt

What I get actually : prntscr.com/5ujaqd

Kind regards and **thanks ALOT**,

Musa.

Comment: PHP is not running, try [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/function.phpinfo.php) to be sure.

Comment: @Sony what do you mean?

Comment: Your PHP code is not interpreted. So PHP is not correctly installed on your server.

Comment: @Sony do you know how I can install PHP correctly on my server?

Comment: @Musa How are accessing this page? Via a local file system or local/live server?

Comment: Still need help with another problem :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the IP in the form as a hidden field, they can just spoof it or remove it from the form submission.

In your contact.php script, change `$field_ip = $_POST['ip'];` to `$field_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` and it will solve your initial problem and ensure the IP isn't tampered with.

Also, the post field names in your form processor differ from the names used in your HTML.  `$_POST['cf_email']` and `$_POST['cf_message]'` need to be changed to just `$_POST['email']` and `$_POST['message']` since in your HTML you used `email` and `message` as the input names.

Comment: Thanks. Now it almost works :$. Found another problem.. If I type in a e-mail, a subject, and a message, it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

If the file extension of the code which you have the html in is not php (or some other extension which apache will handle as php) that is exactly what will happen. 
Any file which you are using php in must have an extension that is handled as php. 
Try changing your file extension to .php

Comment: Ah, I think I know get it. I saved the page as secure.html and I need to try to save it as secure.php?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, has your form page maybe the .html extension and not .php ?
If it's .html, apache will not let php interprete it.

---

Edit :

For your third problem, have you checked that all inputs have the same `name=`as the `$_post` or that they're all between the `<form>` tags  ?

Edit :
Ok the reason is because you need to call you emails info like this :

You have your inputs named like this one :

```
<input name="message">
```

So to get what is written in it :

```
$field_message = $_POST['message'];
```

So basically, in `$_POST`you get the infos of your `<inputs>` from your `<form>` with the name of your `<inputs>`

Hope you're understanding me ..

Comment: Really don't get it anymore. It's sending an email but not with the subject, message, or the e-mail. It says name, and then the e-mail without @  hotmail.com or @ gmail.com and I'm now really getting frustrated.

Comment: Thanks, all of you, everything works perfectly! I wish I could do something more that is better then only saying thanks.